# TFS - how do I sum child task hours to parent

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-aggregator

TFS Web-client provides a "board" view under the backlog tab which shows the sum of Remaining work for a User Story based on the Sum of Remaining Work for it's child tasks.

[image: TFS Web-client View with Parent Summation of Hours]

I have also tried exporting to Excel and using a Pivot table, but there are no obvious links between the work items (as far as I can tell).

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021734/sum-of-parent-child-and-parent-nodes) question but I can't tell if that is the same idea.

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958047/how-to-sum-for-a-parent-child-relationship-in-ms-access) item might be similar, but no responses were received yet.

Can it be done out-of-the-box in Visual Studio TFS?

Does it require coding?

Are there plugins available? I've looked at TFSAggregator on Github and that might work but I'd like to avoid server-side plugins if possible.

Answer (score 1):

One of the many uses of [TFS Aggregator](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator)... it is even one of their sample use cases!

## Example Uses

- Update the state of a Bug, PBI (or any parent) to "In Progress" when a child gets moved to "In Progress"
- Update the state of a Bug, PBI (or any parent) to "Done" when all children get moved to "Done" or "Removed"
- Update the "Work Remaining" on a Bug, PBI, etc with the sum of all the Task's "Work Remaining".
- Update the "Work Remaining" on a Sprint with the sum of all the "Work Remaining" of its grandchildren (i.e. tasks of the PBIs and Bugs in the Sprint).
- Sum up totals on a single work item (i.e. `Dev Estimate + Test Estimate = Total Estimate`)

Comment: I did see that one but trying to avoid server-side plug-ins if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can rollup estimated and actual work using Project. Because Microsoft Project has a scheduling engine, it automatically will generate a rollup of summary tasks. Rollup provides summed values of select fields for all child work items of a parent.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn769080(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: SammyB doesn't want to use a server side plugin, so this is a workaround.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to do this, however there is an issue when a Task's State value is set to "Removed", the rollup values should not be calculated for that Task.  In the policy file, I've got the if condition like so:

```
    <rule name="RollupTasks" appliesTo="Task"><![CDATA[
    string wfState = (string) self.Fields["State"].Value;
    if (wfState="Removed" && self.HasParent()) ...
```

But that didn't work.  I've also tried:

```
    <rule name="RollupTasks" appliesTo="Task"><![CDATA[
    if (self.HasParent() && self[System.State]="Removed") ...
```

..but this doesn't seem to work.  Am I close?

Comment: Sounds like a possibility but editing the policy file might be a challenge. Is the policy file on the server or is it editable on the page?

Comment: You should use inequality (`!=`) to skip the Removed state.

Comment: @SammyB: Policy file resides on the server.

Comment: @GiulioVian: So if we go with the second code block up there, you're answer got me to the right one (I think).  I do want the `[System.State]="Removed"` because that together with `sef.HasParent` gives me the linked User Story, _but_ - I should be using `parent.[System.State]`, not `self.[System.State]`.  Pretty silly mistake, but is my assumption correct?  I will go and test this out next chance I get and report back.  Thank you!

Comment: To aggregate a children value to the parent skipping some children you must have a test to avoid unnecessary computation -- this is the `if (self.HasParent() && ((string)self["System.State"])!="Removed")` test; but you have also to skip aggregating unwanted children e.g. `var sum = self.Parent.Chilldren.Where(c => ((string)c["System.State"])!="Removed").Sum(c => c.GetField<double>("`field`",0.0);`

Comment: Thanks Giulio -- hadn't considered that.  Unfortunately this item has been deferred so I don't have any results yet.  When and if I get them, I'll post.